# Require.js keep infinite reloading

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want to minify my requirejs project by `r.js -o app.build.js`

After finishing it, the result breaks my website.

As the attached clip, you can see the page is keeping reloading itself and the console show the minified module reloaded again and again

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQvWQ28nG1c&feature=youtu.be

Any idea?

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite/js/require.js" 
         data-main="http://mysite/js/dist/app.out.js" defer async="true">
         </script>
```

## buggy page is here

http://www.foolpin.com/review/%E9%BB%83%E5%AE%89

## app.build.js

```
    {
        name: "app.main.js",
        mainConfigFile: 'app.main.js',
        out: "dist/app.out.js",
        optimize: "uglify2",
        preserveLicenseComments: false,
        generateSourceMaps: false,
        optimizeAllPluginResources: false,
        findNestedDependencies: false,
        wrap: true,
        wrapShim: true,
        include: ["./require.js"],

    }
```

## app.main.js

```
    requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            require: './require',
            jquery: './vendor/js/jquery-2.1.1.min',
            underscore: './vendor/js/underscore-min',
            backbone: './vendor/js/backbone-min',
            hbs: './vendor/js/hbs/hbs',
            handlebars: './vendor/js/handlebars-v4.0.5',
        },
        hbs: { // optional
            helpers: true,            // default: true
            templateExtension: 'hbs', // default: 'hbs'
            partialsUrl: ''           // default: ''
        },

        shim: {
            handlebars: {
                exports: 'Handlebars'
            },
            backbone: {
                deps: [
                    'underscore',
                    'jquery'
                ],
                exports: 'Backbone'
            },
            underscore: {
                exports: '_'
            }
        },

    });

    requirejs(["app_config", "app"],function(cfg, App, noop_ahoy){
        return App.initialize();
    });
```

## update

I have multiple files some files has anoymous function for itself

Will it be the problem?

https://gist.github.com/poc7667/555a754a105a88cde13d

```
    define([
        ...
        "jquery"
    ],function(
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the whole page is reloaded, right?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean, I put the embedded html tag in the html file. It works before minifying it. But keep reloading after minifying~~

Comment: What I mean is, is it a full page refresh every time? Or is it just an infinite loop of requests for app.out.js?

Comment: yes, as you can see from the clip. the VIEW was refreshed every few minutes and it also load the identical component multiple time on the VIEW.

Comment: @dannyjolie any idea? I think you could try `http://www.foolpin.com/review/%E9%BB%83%E5%AE%89` you will understand what I mean for the refreshing problem

Comment: If you check the error message in the console, it points you to this: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch. Upon inspection, you big error is this: `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="dadasay" src="http://dadasay.com/plugin/v1/js/dadasay.js"></script>` You tell the script to load itself. So it injects itself, and loads again and again and ....

Comment: @dannyjolie could you see my update thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by something that may be an easy mistake to do. When you use RequireJS you always load the bundle with the code that you supplied or something similar:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite/js/require.js" 
         data-main="http://mysite/js/dist/app.out.js" defer async="true">
         </script>
```

The point being that you just have `src="path/to/require.js` and `data-main="path/to/bundle.js"`. This is important.

Your mistake was including RequireJS in the bundle, and changing the script tag to something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite/js/bundle.js" 
         data-main="http://mysite/js/bundle.js" defer async="true">
         </script>
```

By some glitch in the Matrix, this causes a recursive loading of the same script over and over again, because somewhere inside bundle.js you require `require`, and it fetches bundle.js again and everything goes wild. That's the only thing I can think of. Your page as it stands now doesn't seem to use the bundled script anymore, so I can't verify this.

The solution is to *not* include RequireJS itself in the bundle. It's all there in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply, however I don't think this is the point.  I've remove the inclusion of `require.js` from this `http://dadasay.com/plugin/v1/js/dadasay.min.js`. And if you can take a look on this page `http://www.foolpin.com/review/%E9%BB%83%E5%AE%89` on the console. you will find the exception is undeterministic. So, the problem still exists. T_T

Comment: Hi you helped me a lot, however, I got the `define is not define` exception.could you give me some directions thanks